# Android HTTP POST help needed

Tags: http

Hallo to all members of stackoverflow.

Im new in Android dev,can anybody tell me how to Post data on a website or give me a sampler ?

I want to Post hashes to a online cracker and get the resuld back as string.

```
edit_box = enter the hash
```

sendbutton = send the hash
text_view = resuld

http://xdecrypt.com/#
thanks

EDIT: I take a look @ Live headers and found this resuld
http://xdecrypt.com/ajax/liste.php?hash=759fdfa1a99563aa6309bb6ae27537c564547f62

Here we can add the hash to the Url and the resuld is.

```
document.getElementById('hashresult').value="";document.getElementById('hashresult').value+="759fdfa1a99563aa6309bb6ae27537c564547f62(MySQL)=amande1975 ";
```

Now i want to read this as string anybody can help ?

I want to Display the the Hashtype MySQL and the password amande1975.
And display it as text_view,on the ui.

Thanks again.

EDIT:2 Its Works but how to split the string now ? Anybody can help ?

```
          try {
            String webPage = "http://xdecrypt.com/ajax/liste.php?hash="+hashedit.getText().toString();
            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int numCharsRead;
            char[] charArray = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
            }
            String result = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("*** END ***");

            TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tv2.setText("HashResuld="+sb.toString());
```

EDIT3: Its works ;)

Thanks again for No help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have done a fair bit of research before and ksoap2 has the abilities to do data transfers with webservice urls and I believe that it has other http functionalities which you could use.

http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/

download ksoap2 and import to your project and create you service access layer as such:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;


public class ServiceAccess {

private static String Namespace;
private static String MethodName;
private static String URL;
private SoapSerializationEnvelope Envelope;
private SoapObject SoapRequest;
private SoapPrimitive Response;
private List<PropertyInfo> methodParamList; 

public ServiceAccess(String webserviceUrl, String methodName) throws Exception
{
    setUrl(webserviceUrl);
    setMethodName(methodName);
    setNamespace("http://tempuri.org/");
    SoapRequest = new SoapObject(this.getNamespace(), this.getMethodName());
    methodParamList = new ArrayList<PropertyInfo>();
}
protected String getUrl()
{
    return URL;
}
protected void setUrl(String url)
{
    URL = url;
}
protected String getMethodName()
{
    return MethodName;
}
protected void setMethodName(String methodName)
{
    MethodName = methodName;
}
protected String getNamespace()
{
    return Namespace;
}
protected void setNamespace(String namespace)
{
    Namespace = namespace;
}
protected String SoapAction()
{
    String SOAP_ACTION = this.getNamespace() + this.getMethodName();
    return SOAP_ACTION;
}
protected void CreateSoapRequest() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        if(methodParamList.size()>0){
            for(PropertyInfo propInfo : methodParamList)
            {
        SoapRequest.addProperty(propInfo.getName(), propInfo.getValue());
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }

}
public <T> void addMethodParameters(String paramName, T val)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = new PropertyInfo();
    prop.setName(paramName);
    prop.setValue(val);
    prop.setType(val.getClass());
    methodParamList.add(prop);
}
protected SoapSerializationEnvelope createEnvelope() throws Exception
{
    this.CreateSoapRequest();
    try{

        Envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Envelope.dotNet = true;
        Envelope.setOutputSoapObject(SoapRequest);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }
    return Envelope;
}
public String getResponse() throws Exception
{
    try{

        this.createEnvelope();

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

           androidHttpTransport.call(this.SoapAction(), Envelope);

           Response = (SoapPrimitive) Envelope.getResponse();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }
    return Response.toString();
}

}
```

You can tweak around with it to use various urls of web pages instead of webservice urls.